# How can I stop rounding int values in MySQL

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, discord.js

I am a discord bot developer. I am trying to use MySQL for my discord bot. I am trying to save guild ids in my table. Guild ids rounding automatically when I post to table.
Forexample my guild id is **837465019283745861**. It is posting like **837465019283745900**.
I am using **mysql** module.

My Table:

```
CREATE TABLE guilds (
id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
guild_id BIGINT(18) NOT NULL);
```

My Post Code:

```
const guild = 837465019283745861;
connection.query('INSERT INTO guilds (guild_id) VALUES (?)', guild, function(error, results, fields) {
    if (error) throw error;
    console.log('Data sent!');
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those values don't get rounded in MySQL. That's JavaScript screwing with you because you're not using [`BigInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt):

```
const guild = 837465019283745861n;
```

All numbers in JavaScript are actually floating point unless otherwise specified. This leads to rounding on larger numbers.

Answer (score 2):

To solve this, add 'supportBigNumbers' to your MySQL con

Example:

```js
const database = {
  host: env.db_host,
  port: env.db_port,
  user: env.db_user,
  password: env.db_password,
  database: env.db_name,
  supportBigNumbers: true // BigInt not rounded now
};
```

See more on: https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql#getting-the-id-of-an-inserted-row